# Ruby Rails - Snippets from a project that don't seem so eloquent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm brand new to both Ruby and Rails, and while all the following works, it seems a bit messy.

This is on a classified model to generate WHERE/AND WHERE clauses based on whether or not the user supplies a value through a dropdown. I'm not sure if there's a more Active Recordy way of doing this:

```
class Classified < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :car_id, :owner_id, :owner, :price, :condition, :description, :mileage
   belongs_to :car
   belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
   has_one :model, :through => :car
   has_one :make, :through => :model
   has_many :pictures
 scope :filter_active_cars, lambda { |options| 
 filter = {}
 filter[:cars] = {:year => options[:year]} unless options[:year].empty?
 filter[:makes] = {:id => options[:make]} unless options[:make].empty?
 filter[:models] = {:id => options[:model]} unless options[:model].empty?

 joins(:car, :model, :make) 
 .where(filter)
 .includes(:car, :model, :make)
 }
```

The view has this

```
=select_tag('car[year]', options_for_select(years, :selected => @selected_year))
=collection_select(:car, :make, Make.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => '- Make -', :selected => @selected_make}) 
=collection_select(:car, :model, @selected_make ? Model.where(:make_id => @selected_make) : Model.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => '- Model -', :selected => @selected_model})
```

This is the way I'm passing the "select state" on the classified view. The controller has this snippet in the index action. This is so when a user filters a result and submits the form, the corresponding select box has the same value for the form helpers above.

```
if params[:car]
  params[:car].each do |option, value|
    next if value.empty?
    eval("@selected_#{option} = #{value}")
  end
end
```

On the form partial to generate and edit a classified. Obviously the chaining of &&s sucks, but it's the only way to get the default selection on new, edit, and when a user submits a new form that contains errors.

```
=select_tag('car[year]', options_for_select(years, :selected => @classified.car.nil? ? nil : @classified.car.year), :prompt => "- Year -")
=collection_select(:make, :id, Make.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => '- Make -', :selected => (@classified.car && @classified.car.make && @classified.car.make.try(:id))}) 
=collection_select(:car, :model_id, Model.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => '- Model -', :selected => (@classified.car && @classified.car.model && @classified.car.model.try(:id))})
```

Comment: I think you'd better split your question into several

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can convert this:

```
scope :filter_active_cars, lambda { |options| 
 filter = {}
 filter[:cars] = {:year => options[:year]} unless options[:year].empty?
 filter[:makes] = {:id => options[:make]} unless options[:make].empty?
 filter[:models] = {:id => options[:model]} unless options[:model].empty?

 joins(:car, :model, :make) 
 .where(filter)
 .includes(:car, :model, :make)
 }
}
```

to this:

```
scope :filter_active_cars, lambda do |options| 
 with_option(:car, 'cars.year', :year).
 with_option(:make, 'makes.id', :make).
 with_option(:model, 'models.id', :model)
end

scope :with_option, lambda do |assoc, column, option|
  (options[option].present? ?
    joins(assoc).where(column => options[option]) :
    self).
  includes(assoc)
end
```

You can reuse the `with_option` scope in other models

Comment: I would further just stop using scopes, and instead use methods. Scopes are pretty much a weird way to define a singleton method on a ActiveRecord-behaving class that MUST return an ActiveRecord::Relation & has infinite Arity. Better to have a real method with real Arity that can return anything.

Comment: the fact that a scope MUST return a relation is the reason we use scopes. I'm not a big fan of those, but at least when you use one you know what to expect from it. As to @Alexey's solution, +1 - that's probably what i'll come up with ; one could go further and abstract this behavior with metaprogramming. This would make a nice macro like `filter :active_cars, options: {cars: {year: :year}, makes: {make: :id}, models: {model: :id}}`. The macro would reflect on associations, build necessary scopes and map params keys to columns.